# Computation of $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} n^{1/2^i}$

Tags: summation, asymptotics

Basically, I'm just having issues computing this sum:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} n^{1/2^i}
$$

where $m = \log_{2}({\log_{2}({n})})$.

I need it in terms of $n$, as it's part of a runtime that I'm attempting to bound in order to get its $\Theta$.

Comment: How precise do you need it? For $n \geqslant 2$, the term for $i = 0$ gives the lower bound $n$ for the sum. To get an upper bound, it may be good enough to use $n^{1/2^i} \leqslant \frac{n}{2^i}$ for the considered $i$.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing--there was another $n$ term in the runtime and I stated that since that summation was a sum of successively smaller powers of $n$, they would all be overpowered asymptotically by $n$. 

I'm not sure if this was the right thing to do though; the bounds of the summation depend on $n$ so I'm not sure its appropriate to cancel the whole thing out...